# login session in unity

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

any solution...how can i get data(profile) when user log in the game

this is my login in unity

```
  $username = $_POST['logUserName'];
  $pass = $_POST['logPassword'];



 $checkinfo = "Select * from gameuserinfo where UName = '".$username."' and 
 Password = '".$pass."'";
 $checkinforesult = mysqli_query($connect, $checkinfo);

     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($checkinforesult);
     $count=mysqli_num_rows($checkinforesult);


      if ($count > 0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['member_id']=$row['UserID'];
        echo "Successfuly login";
        }
        else{
        echo "Username or Password is incorrect!";
        }
```

Comment: this is my profile code 

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {
  $id = $_SESSION['member_id'];
  $selectinfo = mysqli_query("Select * from gameuserinfo where UserID='".$id."'");
  $checkselectinfo = mysqli_query($connect,$selectinfo);

  echo "".$rows['FName']."";

}

Comment: any errors? Did you check your connection to database?

Comment: no errors.. but when i log in no data posting .. here my code in profile 


session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {
  $id = $_SESSION['member_id'];
  $selectinfo = mysqli_query("Select * from gameuserinfo where UserID='".$id."'");
  $checkselectinfo = mysqli_query($connect,$selectinfo);

  echo "".$rows['FName']."";

}

Comment: it is possible to use login session in web to unity ?